# State changes are not being reflected in ReactJS

Tags: react-hooks, setstate

So here I have some elements mapped out based on state. I need the elements to reflect the current state after I set state. After hours of researching, I figured updating the variable with a spread operator would force my component to re-render when I set state with said variable. However, the state changes are not being reflected without refreshing.

```js
const updateCurrentChat = () => {
 let filtered = {}
 findChat.forEach((chat) => {
  chat.psuedoID.includes(userInfo._id) &&
  chat.psuedoID.includes(currentTarget._id)
   ? (filtered = { ...chat }) // updating variable
   : console.log(chat)
 })
 setPMData(filtered) // setting state
}

function PrivateMessages() {
 const { pmData } = useContext(newContext)

 return (
  <>
   <PrivateChatArea>
    {pmData
     ? pmData.messages.map((messages) => {
        return (
         <PrivateChatContent id={messages.messageID}>
          {messages.message}
         </PrivateChatContent>
        )
       })
     : null}
   </PrivateChatArea>
  </>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Hi @Romeo Richardson,

You can use `useEffect` hook to ensure that the component re-renders when the `pmData` state changes.

```js
function PrivateMessages() {
 const { pmData } = useContext(newContext)
 const [, setRerender] = useState(0)

 useEffect(() => {
  setRerender((rerender) => rerender + 1)
 }, [pmData])

 return (
  <>
   <PrivateChatArea>
    {pmData
     ? pmData.messages.map((messages) => {
        return (
         <PrivateChatContent id={messages.messageID}>
          {messages.message}
         </PrivateChatContent>
        )
       })
     : null}
   </PrivateChatArea>
  </>
 )
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `useEffect`. Then, you can use `React.memo`. You only need to export your component like this `export default React.memo(PrivateMessages);`.